# CSV file Reading rows in Python

Tags: python, indexing, file-io, row

I'm beginner in python, I'm trying to read a csv and to extract some of the result in another file:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv') as csvfile:
    readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in readCSV:
        print(row[0])
```

I get the error `IndexError: list index out of range`. It happens when I select a row which doesn't exist. However, my csv as 5 columns and I can't isolate any of them.

Comment: try with `print(row)`

Comment: Your code looks ok. Is the delimiter really comma in the file?

Comment: Can you share content of `test.csv`?

Comment: The print(row) command work but i'm trying to show a specific columns not all of them
@alderven i used my bank statetement but it looks like this : 15/01/20;1501208734;* BOUQUET ;-8    
already tried tu use ";" instead of commas does'nt change anything

Answer (score 0):

Use the python **Pandas** library for File reading.

Make sure the encoding format for the CSV File.

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("file_name.csv")
data.head() //it will print the first 5 rows
//for 1 row
data.head(1)
```

check this, and you'll get the answer for yoru question

Comment: No Problem, 
Python Pandas Libraries is a better option to analyze data.